# Existence only as a result of its presupposition?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Is there an analogy in logic to the paradox that a concept comes into existence only by presupposing it as already existing?

Comment: See "Russell's Paradox." There, assuming a certain set exists simply because you can unambiguously define it leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare with one of the basic results of *mathematical logic* :

> **Model Existence Lemma** If $\Gamma$ is a *consistent* set of sentences, then
>   $\Gamma$ has a model.

We can paraphrase it as follows :

> "if a concept is non-contradictory, than it is instantiated."

See :

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA97) (5th ed - 2013), page 97.